# IntelliJ Kotlin build target jvm version

Tags: kotlin

When using a squeezebox in a Kotlin Project I run into the trouble of having a `ClassNotFoundException` for `javafx.scene.control.skin.BehaviorSkinBase`.

The issue seems to be a faulty set jvm target, because when I compile abd package with Maven (with jvmTarget = 1.8) and then manually run it works just fine.

1. My Project SDK ist set to 11.0.3 (under `Project Structure`->`Project Settings`->`Project`)
2. My Target Platform is set to JVM 1.8 (under `Project Structure`->`Project Settings`->`Facets`)
3. My Target JVM Version is set to 1.8 (under `Settings`->`Build, Execution, Deployment`->`Compiler`->`Kotlin Compiler`)
4. JRE ist set to 11.0.3 (under `Run/Debug Configurations`)
5. Target Bytecode Version is set to 1.5

How do I correctly set the target JVM version?